# Java: Count frequency of specific words and write to file

Tags: java, text, frequency

I want to read all text files in folder and count specific words in each files, then write frequency of words to a txt file. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    String[] array = new String[]{"beautiful", "good", "extraordinary", "wonderful", "like",
            "proud","brilliant","great","well", "perfect"};
    int[] wordCount = new int[]{0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};

    File path = new File("development/text");

    for(File file: path.listFiles()){

        PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt",true));            
        FileInputStream fin =  new FileInputStream(file);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fin);

        for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
        {
                        wordCounter = 0;
                        while (s.hasNext()) 
                        {
                             if (s.next().equals(array[i])) {
                                 wordCount[i]++;
                             }
                        }                        
        }

        writer.println(wordCount[0] + "," + wordCount[1] + "," + wordCount[2] + "," + 
                wordCount[3] + "," + wordCount[4] + "," +wordCount[5] + "," +wordCount[6] 
                + "," +wordCount[7] + "," + wordCount[8] + "," + wordCount[9]);
        fin.close();
        s.close();
        writer.close();
    }
}
```

However, my code only read first element of array (beautiful). Other elements output are 0 despite they occur in text file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Invert the order of your loops. Rather than going "for each word in the array, read the file word-by-word and see if there is a match" you need "for each word in the file, check it against each word in the array".

The issue with your current implementation is that it does not "rewind" the file. Once the end of file is reached on the first word, there's no going back on the file and starting from the beginning. However, starting from the beginning of the file is a lot more expensive than starting from the beginning of an array, so inverting loop order is the optimal solution:

```
while (s.hasNext()) {
    String word = s.next();
    for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
        if (word.equals(array[i])) {
            wordCount[i]++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Move the line `Scanner s = new Scanner(fin);` above `while ( s.hasNext() )`

OR

actually as dasblinkenlight told, you should reverse order of loop, also I found couple of issues with your code :
a) The PrintWriter should be really above your listFiles loop
b) The fin.close(), s.close().... all should be outside the main for loop.

With the above changes the code will be something like :

```
PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileWriter("result.txt",true));  
for(File file: path.listFiles())
 {


        FileInputStream fin =  new FileInputStream(file);
        Scanner s = new Scanner(fin);

        while ( s.hasNext() )
        {
            if ( Arrays.asList( array ).contains( s.next() ) ) 
            {
                 wordCount[i]++;
            }

        }


 }

 writer.println(wordCount[0] + "," + wordCount[1] + "," + wordCount[2] + "," + 
                wordCount[3] + "," + wordCount[4] + "," +wordCount[5] + "," +wordCount[6] 
                + "," +wordCount[7] + "," + wordCount[8] + "," + wordCount[9]);
        fin.close();
        s.close();
        writer.close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You have read the whole file, counting the occurrences of the first word, "beautiful". When you start counting the second word, your `Scanner s` is already at the end of the file, so it returns you nothing.